# Replace random number from string with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i need to replace the random string after underscore here is my code

```
var map_list_tmpl_pre = '<div>some odd</div><ul><li class="single_map_list" onClick="showlist(\'parent_id_3aXw\')"></li>
    <li class="single_map_list" onClick="showlist(\'parent_id_3aXw\')"></li>
    </ul>';

$(map_list_tmpl_pre).filter('.single_map_list').each(function(index, currentLink) {
    alert(currentLink.outerHTML.replace(/(parent_id_)[0-9][a-z][A-Z]/, 'parent_id_newID'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `[0-9][a-z][A-Z]` to `[0-9a-zA-Z]+`

`[0-9][a-z][A-Z]` would mean one digit followed by one lowercase letter followed by one upper case letter, e.g. this would match:

`5aA`

but this wouldn't:

`5Aa`

So using your current example, it would match `parent_id_3aX` in the `parent_id_3aXw` string, and replace it so it ended up being `parent_id_newIDw`

Using `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` means that one or more of the pattern would match (signified by the `+`.  And it could be any character in the 0-9 and a-z and A-Z ranges, order wouldn't matter.

Alternatively, instead of having to specify both lowercase and uppercase ranges, you could simply add the `i` flag to make it case-insensitive:

`replace(/(parent_id_)[0-9A-Z]+/i`

Also you shouldn't need to wrap `parent_id_` in parentheses, unless you're wanting to reference it later with a back-reference.  This should also work:

`replace(/parent_id_[0-9A-Z]+/i`

Comment: Great Working like charm :) Thanks Duncan